# Silverlight - Fill a rectangle with animation on mouseclick

Tags: silverlight, animation, fill

I want to be able to fill a rectangle with an animation on leftmousebuttondown (this will later be changed to run on load).

My rectangles are drawn to a canvas in code behind based on the data that is passed (one rectangle per row of data)

At the moment they are filled with a static image but I want this Fill to be an animation, a spinner if I can.

I am very new to Silverlight and am not sure how to achieve this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

My code (part) so far.

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Grid" Background="LightGray"></Canvas>
```

CS:

```
public partial class ProductView : UserControl
{
    Processing processingDialog = new Processing();

    private int colsRequired = 0;
    private int rowsRequired = 0;

    private const int minSize = 5;

    private int cellSize = 1;

    public ProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UpdateGrid(ObservableCollection<Product> productList)
    {
        calculateRowsCols(productList);
        drawGrid(productList);
    }

    public void calculateRowsCols(ObservableCollection<Product> productList)
    {
        int tileCount = productList.Count();
        double tileHeight = Grid.ActualHeight;
        double tileWidth = Grid.ActualWidth;

        if (tileCount == 0)
            return;

        double maxSize = Math.Sqrt((tileHeight * tileWidth) / tileCount);

        double noOfTilesHeight = Math.Floor(tileHeight / maxSize);

        double noOfTilesWidth = Math.Floor(tileWidth / maxSize);

        double total = noOfTilesHeight * noOfTilesWidth;
        cellSize = (maxSize < minSize) ? minSize : Convert.ToInt32(maxSize);

        while ((cellSize >= minSize) && (total < tileCount))
        {
            cellSize--;
            noOfTilesHeight = Math.Floor(tileHeight / cellSize);
            noOfTilesWidth = Math.Floor(tileWidth / cellSize);
            total = noOfTilesHeight * noOfTilesWidth;
        }

        rowsRequired = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(tileHeight / cellSize));
        colsRequired = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(tileWidth / cellSize));
    }

    private void drawCell(int row, int col, string label, Color fill)
    {
        Rectangle innertec = new Rectangle();
        innertec.Height = cellSize * 0.7;
        innertec.Width = cellSize * 0.9;
        innertec.StrokeThickness = 1;
        innertec.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/loading.png", UriKind.Relative));
        innertec.Fill = imageBrush;

        Grid.Children.Add(innertec);
        Canvas.SetLeft(innertec, (col * cellSize) + ((cellSize - innertec.Width) / 2));
        Canvas.SetTop(innertec, row * cellSize + 4);

        Border productLabelBorder = new Border();
        Grid.Children.Add(productLabelBorder);
        Canvas.SetLeft(productLabelBorder, col * cellSize);
        Canvas.SetTop(productLabelBorder, row * cellSize);

        TextBlock productLabel = new TextBlock();
        productLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0, innertec.Height + 5, 0, 5);
        productLabel.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        productLabel.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
        productLabel.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
        productLabel.MaxWidth = cellSize;
        productLabel.Height = cellSize * 0.3;
        productLabel.Width = cellSize;
        productLabel.Text = label;
        productLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        productLabel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        productLabel.FontSize = cellSize * 0.13;

        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(productLabel, label);
        productLabelBorder.Child = productLabel;

    }

    public void drawGrid(ObservableCollection<Product> data)
    {
        int dataIndex = 0;
        Grid.Children.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsRequired; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colsRequired; j++)
            {

                Product product = (dataIndex < data.Count) ? data.ElementAt(dataIndex) : null;

                if (product != null)
                {
                    drawCell(i, j, product.productName, Colors.White);
                }
                dataIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help anyone can give, even a pointer in the right direction would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try creating custom control which will encapsulate everything you want from rectangle to do.
you can add new VisualState "MouseDownState" and do required animatin in xaml.
Please let me know if you need more details regarding the implementation.
late simply add new control instead of rectangle.